# Is there a nice description of infinite coproduct in the category of modal spaces

Tags: general-topology, category-theory, duality-theorems, modal-logic

Let us consider the category of modal spaces, whose objects are pair $(X,R)$ with $X$ a Stone space and $R$ a closed binary relation on $X$ such that 
$$ \lbrace x \mid \exists y \in O : x \mathrel{R} y \rbrace $$ is clopen for every clopen $O$ and whose morphism are continuous functions $f$ such that

- $x \mathrel{R} y$ implies $f(x) \mathrel{R} f(y)$,
- $f(x) \mathrel{R} y$ implies there exists $z$ such that $x \mathrel{R} z$ and $f(z) = y$.

I wanted to know if there exist a nice description of the coproduct of an infinite family $(X_i,R_i)$ in this category and where to find this description, I'm somehow thinking of $(\beta(\coprod X_i), (\coprod R_i)^-)$, with $\beta(\coprod X_i)$ the Stone-Cech compactification of the disjoint union and with $(\coprod R_i)^-$ the closure of $\coprod R_i$ in $(\beta(\coprod X_i))^2$.

Comment: Have you tried to verify the universal property for your candidate? Even if it turns out to be wrong, you might get an insight how to correct it.

Comment: Not yet, because I'm still stuck proving that the map that go from $(X_i,R_i)$ to the candidate coproduct is actually a morphism.